# Injecting CSS into the layout from within a zf2 module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm almost done writing a very simple module for zf2. One thing I'd like my module to do is to inject some css to the layout so that the HTML it generates displays in a nicer way.

Is this possible to do from within a module? If so, how?

EDIT: Thank you all for the prompt responses. However I think I probably didn't explain myself very clearly. When I say "inject some css" I mean taking a string of css and having it actually rendered INSIDE the layout. I didn't mean linking to an external css file or having an asset manager publish my files like the answers so far have suggested.

Comment: please provide us form code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by form. I'm not trying to do a form at all.

Comment: Im on my phone right now, so I wont be able to give a Good anwer. But maybe an asset handler like assetic could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable to your layout for where you'd like the CSS to be inserted:

```
<a href="#" style="<?php echo($this->CSS); ?>">Some Link</a>
```

Then in your Controller, load and assign it however you'd like:

```
$this->layout()->CSS = "CSS";
$this->layout()->CSS = $this->getRequest()->getPost('CSStoInject');
$this->layout()->CSS = fopen(), curl(), etc.
```

Answer (score 8):

See [Publishing assets from modules in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301385/publishing-assets-from-modules-in-zend-framework-2) or [How to merge Zend Framework 2 module public directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296920/how-to-merge-zend-framework-2-module-public-directories) for discussion of the options you have for pushing public assets from a module.

And in addition to pushing your module assets to public, you could put the append into a triggered method like onBootstrap:

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $headLink = $sm->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('headLink');
    $headLink->appendStylesheet('/assets/MyModule/css/mystylesheet.css');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something like:

```
$sm = $this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$helper = $sm->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('headLink');
$helper->prependStylesheet('/css/mystylesheet.css');
```

in Your module controller.

**EDIT:**

If you want to store css style in module, You can either render it in Your layout file (head section) or, the better way, create another route in module, for example `/get/style/[:name]`. This route point to another action which returns only plain text/css document. More or less :)